# Proper reuse of Axes in GeoDataFrame.plot()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I want to draw a simple choropleth map of NYC with binned # of yellow cab rides. My gpd.DataFrame looks like this:

```
   bin  cnt                                              shape
0   15    1  POLYGON ((-74.25559 40.62194, -74.24448 40.621...
1   16    1  POLYGON ((-74.25559 40.63033, -74.24448 40.630...
2   25    1  POLYGON ((-74.25559 40.70582, -74.24448 40.705...
3   27    1  POLYGON ((-74.25559 40.72260, -74.24448 40.722...
4   32   12  POLYGON ((-74.25559 40.76454, -74.24448 40.764...
```

where `bin` is a number of region, `cnt` is target variable of my plot and `shape` column is just a series of `shapely` rectangles composing one covering the whole New York.

Drawing NYC from shapefile:

```
usa = gpd.read_file('shapefiles/gadm36_USA_2.shp')[['NAME_1', 'NAME_2', 'geometry']]
nyc = usa[usa.NAME_1 == 'New York']
ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 2, 2], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-74.25559, -73.70001, 40.49612, 40.91553], ccrs.Geodetic())    
ax.add_geometries(nyc.geometry.values, 
                  ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  facecolor='#1A237E');
```

[image: nyc]

Drawing choropleth alone works fine:

```
gdf.plot(column='cnt', 
         cmap='inferno', 
         scheme='natural_breaks', k=10, 
         legend=True)
```

[image: choropleth]

But if I put `ax` parameter:

```
gdf.plot(ax=ax, ...)
```

the output is

```
<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

**EDIT:**

Got it working with following code:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cmap = plt.get_cmap('summer')
my_cmap = cmap(np.arange(cmap.N))
my_cmap[:,-1] = np.full((cmap.N, ), 0.75)
my_cmap = ListedColormap(my_cmap)

gax = gdf.plot(column='cnt', 
               cmap=my_cmap, 
               scheme='natural_breaks', k=10,
               figsize=(16,10),
               legend=True, 
               legend_kwds=dict(loc='best'))
gax.set_title('# of yellow cab rides in NYC', fontdict={'fontsize': 20}, loc='center');
nyc.plot(ax=gax, 
         color='#141414',
         zorder=0)
gax.set_xlim(-74.25559, -73.70001)
gax.set_ylim(40.49612, 40.91553)
```

[image]

Comment: Are your figure and axes objects still present before you call `gdf.plot(ax=ax, ...)`? Also, does it change anything if you define your axes using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})`? And isn't it possible to plot everything only with geopandas calls, such as in here (http://geopandas.org/mapping.html)?

Comment: 1) axes object surely exists
2) adding plt.subplots hasn't made difference
3) problem is my data is counted towards synthetic rectangle bins, not actual NYC counties

Comment: Two more things. Why do you have a semi-column at the end of this call `ax.add_geometries(nyc.geometry.values, 
                  ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  facecolor='#1A237E');`? And what if you assign the result of this call to a varibale, say `base`, and use `ax=base` in the `gdf.plot()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When only doing this with `.plot` calls from geopandas this seems to work fine. Had to make up some data as I don't have yours. Let me know if this helps somehow. Code example should work as is in IPython.

```
%matplotlib inline
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from random import random

crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
num_squares = 10

# load natural earth shapes

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# create random choropleth

minx, miny, maxx, maxy = world.geometry.total_bounds

x_coords = np.linspace(minx, maxx, num_squares+1)
y_coords = np.linspace(miny, maxy, num_squares+1)

polygons = [Polygon([[x_coords[i], y_coords[j]],
                     [x_coords[i+1], y_coords[j]],
                     [x_coords[i+1], y_coords[j+1]],
                     [x_coords[i], y_coords[j+1]]]) for i in 
range(num_squares) for j in range(num_squares)]

vals = [random() for i in range(num_squares) for j in range(num_squares)]

choro_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'cnt' : vals, 'geometry' : polygons})
choro_gdf.crs = crs

# now plot both together

ax = choro_gdf.plot(column='cnt', 
                    cmap='inferno', 
                    scheme='natural_breaks', k=10, 
                    #legend=True
                    )

world.plot(ax=ax)
```

This should give you something like the following
[image: choropleth]

--Edit, if you're worried about setting the correct limits (as you're doing with the boroughs), please just paste the following to the end of the code (for example)

```
ax.set_xlim(0, 50)
ax.set_ylim(0, 25)
```

This should then give you:

[image: zoomed in image]

Comment: updated my answer to provide correctly working code, the only thing is missing in your answer is wrong zorder